# Confusion about scope of smart pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, smart-pointers

Suppose I have the following function with some hypothetical class `Obj` that can hold a (smart) pointer to an object of type `Foo`:

```
class Obj {
  public:
    void setFoo(std::shared_ptr<Foo>);
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo;
};

Obj::setFoo(std::shared_ptr<Foo> fooPtr) {
  foo = fooPtr;
}

Obj* getObj() {
  std::shared_ptr<Foo> fooPtr = std::make_shared<Foo>(new Foo());
  Obj *obj = new Obj();
  obj->setFoo(fooPtr);
  return obj; 
}
```

When will my smart pointer be deleted?

1. When we return from `getObj` because it's now out of the function's scope and `obj` is not pointed-at "smartly"?
2. Whenever `obj` is deleted later in my program?

My tests make me think its 2., but a colleague thinks it's 1.

I couldn't find documentation that would answer my question, as all explanations of smart pointers I read didn't do anything with the pointer that would make it escape the scope of its creator...

Comment: No one can answer your question without seeing the definition of `Obj`. Please, provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: BTW, `std::make_shared<Foo>(new Foo());` does not make much sense (unless a constructor of `Foo` accepts a pointer to `Foo` as an argument). Also, consider adding a plain _C++_ tag to your question. A much more people might be attracted to it then.

Comment: @DanielLangr Ok, I'll edit further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointer allocated and saved inside `fooPtr` **isn't** destroyed at the end of `getObj()` because, after `setFoo()`, the are **two** shared-pointers containing it.

At the end of `getObj()`, the first containing shared-pointer is destroyed (`fooPtr`) but survive the other: the `foo` member of the `Obj` object pointed by `obj`.

`obj` is returned by `getObj()`, so the second shared-pointer survive at the end of `getObj()`.

Comment: Looks like my question is ill-asked. I'll refine it.

Comment: @Axioplase - Answer improved.

Comment: Note that the instance of Foo inside Obj can be leaked if you leak that instance of Obj.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `std::make_shared<Foo>(new Foo())` is an anti-pattern. If `std::make_shared` throws an exception (e.g. `std::bad_alloc`) or `Foo` constructor called by `std::make_shared<Foo>` throws an exception, the result of `new Foo()` never gets deleted and hence leak memory.

Also, `obj` is not managed using a smart pointer and hence it may leak.

A safer version:

```
struct Foo {};

class Obj : std::enable_shared_from_this<Obj> {
    Foo foo;
public:
    void setFoo(Foo const& f) {
        foo = f;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Foo> getFoo() {
        return std::shared_ptr<Foo>(this->shared_from_this(), &foo); // aliasing constructor.
    }
};

std::shared_ptr<Obj> getObj() {
    auto obj = std::make_shared<Obj>();
    // obj->setFoo(Foo(<args>); // if necessary
    return obj;
}

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Obj> obj = getObj();
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo = obj->getFoo();
}
```

Note that both shared pointers `obj` and `foo` here refer to the same underlying object `Obj`, because of using `std::shared_ptr` aliasing constructor. Once you have an object managed via `std::shared_ptr`, you can create `std::shared_ptr` to its members without having to turn those members into `std::shared_ptr`.